# Trying to compile Orion with lucid ubuntu 10.04

Tags: fiware-orion

When executing make Orion contextbroker on Ubuntu 10.04, I get the following error:

```
fiware-orion-develop/src/lib/mongo/db/../util/optime.h: In member function ‘long long unsigned int mongo::OpTime::asDate() const’:
fiware-orion-develop/src/lib/mongo/db/../util/optime.h:95: error: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
```

Could somebody help me to solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

The following [issue at Orion github repository](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/11) includes some information to build on Ubuntu. Although the issue refers to Ubuntu 13.10, maybe it helps.